# Timing a program running with popen

Tags: c++

i'm kind of new to C++ and I'm trying to build a program that run a command with popen, and gets the execution time of the popen()ed command.

I've tried with the clock() function but it will only get the time that takes the popen() to fork and pipe and not the actual sub command execution time.

So the question is: is there a way to check the execution time of a popen()ed command?

```
string command = "some time consuming command";
FILE *process; 
char buff[1024];

char cCommand[command.size() + 1];
strcpy(cCommand, command.c_str());

fflush(NULL);
process = popen(cCommand, "r");

if (process != NULL) {
    while (!feof(process)) {
        
        fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), process);
        // Doing something with my output
    }
    
    r = pclose(process);
}
return WEXITSTATUS(r);
```

EDIT: I also forgot to mention that i tried to use the unix `/bin/bash -c time <subprogram path>` but everytime it returns a time of 0, it actually doesn't even execute the subprogram, but just the time command

Comment: Well, if you want to time how long it takes the entire program to run, from the time you popen it, to the time you pclose it, isn't that what you need to measure, instead of just the popen command?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that at runtime i won't know the actual code that would be running (take aside security issues for now). This program will actually be integrated in a bigger system, an user will submit his code and i will test it, that's why i can't measure the popen()ed program itself

Comment: Look into [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Comment: That's not what I wrote. Reread what I wrote. You need to measure how long it takes until ***after*** pclose returns. Take the clock value before calling `popen()`, and then again ***after*** `pclose()` returns, and that's the time it took for the program to run.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah ok, sorry i misunderstood, english is not my first language, anyway i tried what you suggested (before popen() and after pclose()) with clock and it's not working for me , it always return 0 clock cycles, but i also tried using std::chrono as suggested before and it looks like it's working (before popen() and after pclose()), i will post updated code soon

Comment: Note that `clock` measures CPU time (not wall clock time) used by the current process, so if the current process is simply blocking waiting on the child terminating then it shouldn't come as any surprise that it reports zero seconds.

Comment: You can run your program with [`/usr/bin/time`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html), it prints the times into `stderr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using std::chrono

```
string command = "some time consuming command";
FILE *process; 
char buff[1024];

char cCommand[command.size() + 1];
strcpy(cCommand, command.c_str());

fflush(NULL);
// Gets the now() time before the command is launched
auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
process = popen(cCommand, "r");

if (process != NULL) {
    while (!feof(process)) {

        fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), process);
        // Doing something with my output 
    }

    r = pclose(process);
    // Gets the now time after the command has terminated
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    // Finish - start = elapsed time
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    time = elapsed_seconds.count();
}

return WEXITSTATUS(r);
```